# Why is there a Xbox games app in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, xbox360

On my website I am doing a review the Xbox-games app on Windows 8.1. And for some reason I don't get it why it should be there? Is there anything extra to your gaming-experience while playing with the Games-app installed? The only reason I can think of is for your messages and progress, but this is also available on [xbox.com](http://www.xbox.com).

Is there any reason why I must install this app?

Comment: I'm not talking about the smartglass-app. I'm talking about the built-in games-app. http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/15a9edda-c1ee-48bc-b670-847c610baf41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Windows 8 includes a new Games app that lets you review your Xbox Live game activity and friends and browse games and content for both your Xbox 360 console and PC. [Source](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-other-devices/windows/windows-8-install-games)

Back in June I went to a Microsoft training that laid out some of the future plans with Windows. The Xbox Games app does essentially what you've surmised; it allows you to connect to your friends, view messages, view games, and write reviews. It is extending the functionality of your Xbox Live to PC based games. This allows your friends to view achievements for those games.

Microsoft also has an initiative to bring more arcade style titles into the Windows experience, which works very well for developers looking to go cross-platform.

Comment: All of this is also available on xbox.com. So there is no need for this app. Anyway, thanks for the info.

Comment: @JeroenDeMeerleer - Everything that exists in a twitter application exists on the twitter website, so there is no need for the hundreds of twitter apps, just because you see no use for it doesn't mean there isn't somebody that thinks its useful.